# Converting Uneven List to Dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, tidyr

I am wondering if there is an elegant and generalizable way to convert mylist to mydf in the example below. I've looked at the [rectangling vignette](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rectangle.html) but the examples for unnest/hoist seem to be on lists that have a regular but not tidy structure.

```
mylist <- list(name = "example",
               idnum = 123,
               cases = list(
                 case1 = list(
                   type = 1,
                   genre = "A"),
                 case2 = list(
                   type = 1,
                   genre = "B"),
                 case3 = list(
                   type = 2,
                   genre = "A"
                 )))

mydf <- data.frame(name = rep("example", 3),
                   idnum = rep(123, 3),
                   cases = c("case1", "case2", "case3"),
                   type = c(1, 1, 2),
                   genre = c("A", "B", "A"))
```

Edit: This gets close to what I want but I am losing the case names

```
mylist %>%
  as_tibble %>%
  unnest_wider(cases)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  name    idnum  type genre
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1 example   123     1 A    
2 example   123     1 B    
3 example   123     2 A
```

Comment: With `purrr`, you can try something like `mylist %>%
 map_at("cases", ~ map_dfr(., data.frame, .id = "cases")) %>%
 as_tibble()`.

Comment: I think this is the right track, with map_if(is_list, ....) we might be able to get the general solution which doesn't require specifying 'cases' that I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

One option is `bind_rows` with `unnest_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
bind_rows(mylist) %>% 
   mutate(case = names(cases)) %>%
   unnest_wider(c(cases))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# name    idnum  type genre case 
#  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#1 example   123     1 A     case1
#2 example   123     1 B     case2
#3 example   123     2 A     case3
```

Or as @Ben suggested in the comments

```
mylist %>% 
     as_tibble %>% 
     mutate(case = names(cases)) %>% 
     unnest_wider(c(cases))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  name    idnum  type genre case 
#  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#1 example   123     1 A     case1
#2 example   123     1 B     case2
#3 example   123     2 A     case3
```

Comment: I am getting the error 'Argument 3 must be length 1, not 3' when I run this code, but I that the mutate line is helpful, so now I can do this with:     `mylist %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(case = names(cases)) %>%
  unnest_wider(c(cases))`

Comment: @Ben could be related to the version of packages